# this.refs no longer available in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

From the changelog for React v0.13:

"ref resolution order has changed slightly such that a ref to a component is available immediately after its `componentDidMount` method is called; this change should be observable only if your component calls a parent component's callback within your `componentDidMount`, which is an anti-pattern and should be avoided regardless"

So, is there a better way to access `this.refs` after the DOM mounts?  I dislike using `setTimeout()`, but that is the best method I see to work on a specific DOM after it mounts.  Is there a replacement method I am missing?  Or, is the best way to attach an `onLoad` method directly to the component?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe you are reading too much into this.

My interpretation is that all refs to child components are available in `componentDidMount`.

The change is that they are not available before the child component's own `componentDidMount` has completed (which happens before the parent component's). And you would only be affected by that if you call some callback from inside `componentDidMount` of the child, and that code tries to use the `ref` immediately. Which seems like an edge-case and, as they say, an anti-pattern.

So "normal usage" should not be impacted by this change.

Please try and report back.

Comment: Thanks, Thilo.  It was my mistake.  I failed to update the react lib.